# bonjour for embedded system

Tags: android, bonjour, mdns

I have followed the steps provided in the install file to initialize the bonjour for embedded system . first I generated the shared ib for bonjour source code for my embedded system and then I initialized it by calling mDNS_Init  api.

Since I just need to browse at my client , I called the browsing function as per dns_sd.h  , but I got the below error .

mDNS_StartBrowse: mDNSPlatformRawTime went backwards by 1669225997 ticks; setting correction factor to 1669225997

11-17 00:28:08.481: D/bonjour(1280): mDNS_StartBrowse: mDNS_Unlock: ERROR! m->timenow aready zero

11-17 00:28:08.481: D/bonjour(1280): DNSServiceBrowse("_appl._tcp.", "local.") failed: mDNS_StartBrowse (-65546)

11-17 00:28:08.490: I/System.out(1280): DNSService call failed -65546

11-17 00:32:24.720: E/ThrottleService(161): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats:

I posted in the  apple forum but I have nit received any help for this problem ..

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment, hope there is an anwer anywhere :)

Comment: Hi. ¿Did you find any solution on this subject? Thank you